# Checking the pix value combination among channels

Tags: python, image

I have an image which I want to turn black and white - the image shape is `(480, 640, 4)`.
[image]

For that matter I turn all values above zero one doing the following:

```
img[img > 0] = 1.0
```

Therefore, most of pixels will have the following values either `[0, 0, 0, 1]`, which is black, or `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, which is white. However, some pixels will have undesired combinations like `[1, 0, 0, 1]` and `[0, 1, 0, 1]`.

[image]

I would like to check the pixel combination at channel level to make sure only black and white would remain.

EDIT:

The way I've found to do it is:

```
img = plt.imread('segm.png')
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if (sum(img[i, j])>1.0 and sum(img[i, j])<4.0):
            img[i, j] = 0.0
```

However, it is a very long loop. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? Find a pixel that ends up with unwanted result, look at its value before the change and try to figure out what's gone wrong.

Comment: @TDG I've found this solution: `img[:, :, 0]`